# Error cannot resolve simbol list with list.setAdapter(adapter)

Tags: android, android-fragments, oncreate

This is my code, it works at 100%:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.t1, container, false);
    final ListView list = (ListView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.list);
    class json extends AsyncTask<String,String, List<MovieModel> > {
        ...
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final List<MovieModel> result) {
            ...
            MainActivity.Adapter adapter = new MainActivity.Adapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row, result);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
            list.setOnItemClickListener
            ...
        }
}
```

but now i need to call json class in another position too:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
....
class json .....
 }

@Override
public void onRefresh() {
    new json();// i can't recall in this way, but i need it
}
```

The problem is list, because i can not pull off from onCreateView because list is not definited if i do.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ....
    new json();
}
class json extends AsyncTask<String,String, List<MovieModel> > {
    ...
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final List<MovieModel> result) {
        ...
        MainActivity.Adapter adapter = new MainActivity.Adapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row, result);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);//this is an error now
```

The error now is "cannot resolve simbol 'list'".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick solution would be to make `list` a class variable.

```
public class MainActivty extends Activity {
    private ListView mList;

    private class json extends AsyncTask<String,String, List<MovieModel> > {
        ...
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final List<MovieModel> result) {
        ...
        mList.setAdapter(adapter);
        ...
    }
}
```

But the better solution would be to pass the `result` from `onPostExecute` back to the MainActivity to update the UI.

```
public class MainActivty extends Activity {
    private ListView mList;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.t1, container, false);
        mList = (ListView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.list);
        ...
    }

    private void updateUI(final List<MovieModel> result> {
        MainActivity.Adapter adapter 
            = new MainActivity.Adapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row, result);
        mList.setAdapter(adapter);
        ...
    }

    private class json extends AsyncTask<String,String, List<MovieModel> > {
        ...
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final List<MovieModel> result) {
        ...
        updateUI(result);
        ...
    }
}
```

In this way, you keep all data processing in your `AsyncTask` and all UI processing in your `Activity`.